# What is the direction of the normal acceleration on an inclined plane?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

I am very confused about the solution that my Professor has provided to an apparently-simple exercise.

For the following box rotating around in an inclined plane, I am asked to find the minimum velocity at the highest point in the trajectory to have circular motion. 
[image]

I know this implies that the normal acceleration must be greater than zero, but when I solve this exercise, I come up with the forces equilibriums:

$$\sum F_y = N\cos(30º) - mg - Tsin(30º) = 0$$
$$\sum F_x = T\cos(30º) - mg - Nsin(30º) = m\frac{v^2}R$$This is taking the traditional X and Y axes.

However, my Professor takes the Y axis perpendicular to the plane and the X axis parallel to it, and comes up with:

$$\sum F_x = T + mgsin(30º)= m\frac{v^2}R$$

Shouldn't he be multiplying the normal acceleration by the $sin(30)$ for this to be valid? I do not understand why he takes the direction of the normal acceleration to be parallel to the plane.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to specify what axes you are using for your frame of reference, since choosing and using a different frame can simplify the question immensely.

So, start by defining a frame of reference with origin at the centre of the circular motion, with the positive $Z$ axis perpendicular to the inclined plane, and thus the $X-Y$ plane in the surface of the inclined plane.

Assume that the moving box is located at the point $B$;  the point in its circular motion farthest ***up*** the inclined plane, and that it is continuing in its circular motion.

Immediately, we know the total force that ***must*** be acting on the box from B to the centre;  it's just the required centripetal force.

Moreover, we know that the only real forces acting on the box ***in the plane of the incline*** are the tension in the string, and the down-slope component of the force of gravity.  The normal force (perpendicular to the inclined plane) can be ignored;  it does not act in a direction to affect the circular motion.

So just equate the real force acting down the slope to the force needed:$$T+mg \sin(30)=\frac{mv^2}{R}$$ and let $T$ go to zero...

Comment: I think my problem is with how to choose the direction of the normal force. I understand it in this case thanks to your explanation, but what if for instance we had a car in a banked curve around a circular track? Then, would the centripetal acceleration be parallel to the plane or just horizontal towards the center of the circle?

Comment: The circular motion must take place in a plane.  The centripetal acceleration is in that plane, directed towards the centre of the circle...  The normal force is, well, normal to the surface; in the case if the banked curve, perpendicular to the road surface...